# Issue understanding CALayer Geometry. Need Assistance

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to understand calayer geometry but having issue understanding this

- **Position** (Its clear to me)
- **Bounds**
  (Apple docs says)The bounds property is a CGRect that provides the size of the layer (bounds.size) and the origin (bounds.origin).

> The bounds origin is used as the origin of the graphics context when
> you override a layer's drawing methods.
>
> I did't get this point regarding bounds.

- **Frame**
  (Apple docs says)

> Layers have an implicit frame that is a function of the position,
> bounds, anchorPoint, and transform properties. Setting a new frame
> rectangle changes the layer's position and bounds properties
> appropriately, but the frame itself is not stored. When a new frame
> rectangle is specified the bounds origin is undisturbed, while the
> bounds size is set to the size of the frame. The layer's position is
> set to the proper location relative to the anchor point. When you get
> the frame property value, it is calculated relative to the position,
> bounds, and anchorPoint properties.
>
> but this is lot more complex and different then this [Stanford university lecture slide 19](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7670972/Standford-CS-193P-05Views-Animation)

- **AnchorPoint** This in the end playing with bounds...making my head spin

Need help.

Thanks, Regards.

Comment: question is i am having problem understanding this calayer geometry concepts

Comment: Stack Overflow is best for specific questions... do you have a question further than "I don't understand"?

Answer (score 3):

Every view has its own co-ordinate system.

The co-ordinate system of any view has its origin at (0,0). Thus, the bounds of any view is the "bounds" of this co-ordinate system ie. (0, 0, width, height).

Position of any view is calculated based on the co-ordinate system of the parent view or `superview`. Which is the frame of any view, which will hence be, (x, y, width, height), where x and y represent the left and top or the position of the top left corner in the parent's co-ordinate system.

The ios documentation explains this using this image

[image: This should explain things much better]

And for the last one, since an AnchorPoint is "inside" a view, it is represented in the view's co-ordinate system and so must use the bounds, just like the `center` property.

This is true for a CALayer as well, where the layers' bounds are defined in their own co-ordinate system and their frames are defined by their superviews. There are quite a few differences, some are direct, like the layers have far deeper control, whereby you can set the zordering and have an anchor point for working with transforms etc. Some are subtle, like for example the frame property of a CALayer is not animatable (ie. changing it in an animation block has no effect).

And, I suggest that you try out smaller programs to understand the differences in addition to just trying to get everything out of a book or two or for that matter even SO.

Comment: I have that uiview doc also opened side by side with core animation calayer, but apple says " While layers and the layer-tree are analogous to views and view hierarchies in many ways, a layer's geometry is specified in a different, and often simpler, manner. All of a layer’s geometric properties, including the layer’s transform matrices, can be implicitly and explicitly animated. " Views and layer geometry are different. Whats the difference between them? Thanks for reply.